# collections.deque get index of element by value

Tags: python, python-2.7, deque

For list we can get index of element `list_name.index(3)`

How to get index of item in deque.

ex:
`d_list = deque([1, 2, 3, 4])` what is the best way to get the index of element 3.

Edit:
I am using Python 2.7.6

Answer (score 6):

Just use it like regular lists:

```
>>> d_list = collections.deque([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> d_list.index(3)
2
```

Edit: This is only possible in Python 3.5 right now

Answer (score 6):

According to the [pythons docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque), if you have python3.5 or better, you can use `index` (as per tobspr's answer).

For older pythons, you can convert the deque to a list and then use `index`:

```
In [5]: from collections import deque

In [6]: d_list = deque([1, 2, 3, 4])

In [7]: list(d_list).index(3)
Out[7]: 2
```

Comment: can we remove from the queue at desired position ?  or we can only remove from ***popleft()*** ?

Comment: Also note documentation [Indexed access is O(1) at both ends but slows to O(n) in the middle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque.maxlen)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Python 2.x, `deque` is not a good choice if you want to do lookup. You can either use `list` or do the following using `enumerate()`:

```
>>> def index(element, queue):
...     for i, ele in enumerate(queue):
...         if ele == element:
...             return i
...     raise ValueError("{} is not in queue".format(element))

>>> index(2, deque([1, 2, 3, 4]))
1
```

Alternatively, you can implement your own queue:

```
>>> class IndexedDeque(deque):
...     def index(self, element):
...         for i, ele in enumerate(self):
...             if ele == element:
...                 return i
...         raise ValueError("{} is not in queue".format(element))    

>>> d_list = IndexedDeque([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> d_list.index(2)
1
```